# UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer problem angular 11 .net core

Tags: .net-core, angular-cli, single-page-application

Ive just taken over an app that has this line of code in startup.cs

spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200")

when the app runs, I get this error

HttpRequestException : no connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Failed to proxy the request to http://localhost:4200 because the request to the proxy target failed: check that the proxy target server is running and accepting requests to http://localhost:4200

I had initially thought this was a sql server error , its similar in syntax to a sql network error, but after some searching its down to spa architecture/design ?

What should the proxy server be ?  Am I missing the activation of a server somewhere ?
Im using .net core 3 and angular 11 (which im new to)
thanks in advance for any help

Comment: If you're new to all this, it might be better not to use ASP.NET Core + Angular as a single project. Just run Angular as usual and make it hit ASP.NET Core as any API. Once you're more familiar with how everything works, the SPA integration of ASP.NET Core will start making more sense

Answer (score 1):

When using `UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer` during development you need to start the angular app as another process at that address- usually this just means `npm run start` in the angular apps directory.

Comment: I executed the command in the ClientApp directory and started the server but I got exactly the same error message.  In powershell I get 'angular live development server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200' running the app from visual studio, its on port 5001

Comment: ng serve --port 4200

Comment: ng serve --port 4200 - the term 'ng' is not recognised

Comment: you dont have the angular cli installed. Please go read the angular getting started guide and docs. https://angular.io/start